# Using ViewModel from dll for UserControl

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I am having a dll which contains a usercontrol and also the viewmodel for the control. I am using this usercontrol in another application. Now i don't know how to set the datacontext to the viewmodel in the dll.

This is the View Code of my application(The Window LayoutControlViewModel is the dll ViewModel):

```
<Window x:Class="TestApplication.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:dll="clr-namespace:WindowLayoutControl.View;assembly=WindowLayoutControl"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <dll:WindowLayoutControl DataContext="{Binding WindowLayoutControlViewModel}"></dll:WindowLayoutControl>
</Grid>
```

Sorry i am pretty new to mvvm and wpf. Thank you in advance.

Comment: How do you use those controls in the dll? Do you call them in xaml and/or code?

Comment: Can you post a sample showing what you're trying to do? It would help to understand your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said that you have both View and ViewModel in that dll, so i'll asume that the ViewModel is in a separate namespace:

```
<Window x:Class="TestApplication.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:dll="clr-namespace:WindowLayoutControl.View;assembly=WindowLayoutControl"
    xmlns:dllViewModel="clr-namespace:WindowLayoutControl.ViewModel;assembly=WindowLayoutControl"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <dll:WindowLayoutControl>
        <dll:WindowLayoutControl.DataContext>
            <dllViewModel:{Name of your view model here}/>
        </dll:WindowLayoutControl.DataContext>
    </dll:WindowLayoutControl>
</Grid>
```